# Acces to method of specific Component since Parent Angular 2

Tags: angular, directive

How can I acces to method of a component :

**my directive.ts :**

```
import { Parent } from '../../_common/Parent';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
})

export class IcheckDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private parentCmp: Parent) {
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-aero',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-aero'
    }).on('ifChecked', function(event) {
      if (jQuery('input').attr('type') === 'radio') {
  // Here how can I call method **selectType** of the component FolderComponent when I check I radio button parentCmp.selectType(jQuery('input[name="filters.type"]:checked').val());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**my Parent.ts**

```
export abstract class Parent {
 }
```

**My component.ts (using icheck)**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Parent } from '../../_common/Parent';

    declare var jQuery: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-folders',
      templateUrl: './folders.component.html',
       providers: [{ provide: Parent, useExisting: FoldersComponent }]
    })
    export class FoldersComponent implements OnInit, Parent {

         name = 'FoldersComponent ';

      constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
      ) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

      selectType(value: string) {
         console.log(value);
      }
    }
```

Here, we can see that I have a method "selectType" in FoldersComponent, so when I want to call it when I check radio button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
          if (jQuery('input').attr('type') === 'radio') {
             // Here how can I call method **selectType** of the component FolderComponent 
            //when I check I radio button parentCmp.selectType(jQuery('input[name="filters.type"]:checked').val());

             parentCmp.selectType();
          }
```

If all your parent components should have the `selectType` method, then just modify the `Parent` class and add that property:

```
export abstract class Parent {
    selectType() {}
 }
```

If some parents will not have it, then you can specify type `any` like this and the compiler won't generate the error:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, @Inject(Parent) private parentCmp:any ) {
```

Comment: Yes, it is what I do but I have this error mark `Property 'selectType' does not exist on type 'Parent'.`